Is requesting the community to peer-review and provide feedback on source code appropriate?
I've been working on a short piece of 6502 assembly and I now have a working implementation.  However, I think it would be useful to get some feedback from community members that are more experienced writing assembly than I am.  A more experienced set of eyes might see 'tricks' or more efficient ways of doing things that have not occurred to me (with my present skills).  This type of feedback could (potentially) help me to be a better assembly programmer, and/or might lead to an improved implementation.  An added side effect might be to help other aspiring assembly programmers learn new approaches as well.
But I have to wonder if it is appropriate to 'shop' code around for peer-review and feedback on RCSE, or would Stack Overflow be the better venue?

See also this similar question and this one.

@dave, thanks for those links.  I wasn't sure if they applied because in my case, I'm not asking for help debugging, nor am I asking for how or why something works; I simply have a block of code I'd like feedback on.  I know RCSE has a bunch of great assembly programmers, so it could be a valuable resource for code review - but asking for a code review is a lousy fit for the Q/A format (it's not really even a question) so it just feels like a bad post (on my part).  I think wizzwizz4 is right to suggest I go to 'Code Review Stack Exchange' instead (which I honestly didn't even know existed).

Stack Overflow would not be suitable. Retrocomputing Stack Exchange would be suitable if the question is about a particular technique or very short snippet, but probably not for a full program. Instead, consider Code Review Stack Exchange, a site dedicated to giving feedback on the source code of working programs.

Ah, derp.  I didn't even realize there was a Code Review Stack Exchange, so thank you for enlightening me!  :-)
